# How can find sum of a column after group by result in mysql

Tags: mysql

Consider this table

| name | amount |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 1 |
| cat | 5 |
| horse | 2 |

Now I want to find sum(amount) group by name like this:

```sql
SELECT name,SUM(amount) s FROM animals GROUP BY name;
```

Result will be like:

| name | s |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 6 |
| horse | 2 |

I want to find  sum(s)

My question is that, is anyone to know how can I find sum(s) with a query

```sql
SELECT SUM(s),(SELECT name, SUM(amount) s FROM animals GROUP BY name);
```

But This query not working.

Please help me

Comment: so.. you wanted the total of the sums?

Comment: Thank you Mr.  but iwant sum of column  with group by result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need in total sum **only** then simply remove GROUP BY:

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) summ
FROM animals;
```

If you need sums for each animal **and** total then use WITH ROLLUP:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(name, 'Total') name, SUM(amount) summ 
FROM animals 
GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Is a query that find sums of each animal in one record not show all of group by record result?

Comment: @EdrisJafarizada Sorry, I cannot understand your question...